# How to implement the tournament method for finding the 2nd largest element in an array?

Tags: tournament

I need the implementation approach of Tournament method for finding the 2nd largest element in an array. I have already searched the Internet but gained nothing. I don't know how to store those elements which lost to the largest element.

Comment: Please supply code of what you tried to do so far and what did not work

Comment: I don't have any code. To code something u must know the approach which I am missing here.